# Como calcular média e mostrar os valores maior e menor?

Tags: sql-server

Comecei a estudar SQL SERVER e de cara deparei com o seguinte problema:

> crie uma função que calcula a média dos alunos e se for MAIOR IGUAL QUE 7 o aluno deve ser considerado aprovado; se não, reprovado.

Como faço isso?

Comment: Bem vinda, evite criar perguntas com títulos em maiúsculo e coloque o que já tentou fazer (código)

Comment: Uma função ou um procedimento? Poderia acrescentar a descrição da tabela?

Comment: Desculpa! minha primeira vez em forum

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

Com a tabela passada pela @LuzineteMaciel

obs: conforme comentado pelo [José Diz](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/57789/jos%C3%A9-diz) foi adicionado verificação se os valores são nulos para evitar retorno com `NULL`

```
SELECT
    dessecod                                AS dessecod,
    MatCod                                  AS MATERIA, 
    (ISNULL(BolNota1, 0) + ISNULL(BolNota2, 0))                 AS SOMA_NOTA,                     
    ((ISNULL(BolNota1, 0) + ISNULL(BolNota2, 0))/2)   AS MEDIA,
    CASE
        WHEN ((ISNULL(BolNota1, 0) + ISNULL(BolNota2, 0))/2) < 7 THEN 'Reprovado'
        else 'Aprovado'
    END                     AS RESULTADO
FROM TbBoletim
GROUP BY
    dessecod,
    MatCod,
    BolNota1,
    BolNota2
```

---

Na pergunta não é informado a descrição da tabela, logo criei uma estrutura e uma query para ilustrar uma possível forma de solucionar o problema

```
CREATE TABLE ALUNOS(
    ID INTEGER IDENTITY,
    NOME VARCHAR(150),
    MATERIA VARCHAR(20),
    NOTA DECIMAL(10,2)
)

INSERT INTO ALUNOS(NOME, MATERIA, NOTA) VALUES
    ('Leonardo', 'Matematica', 8),
    ('Leonardo', 'Matematica', 9),
    ('Leonardo', 'Matematica', 8),
    ('João', 'Matematica', 8),
    ('João', 'Matematica', 8),
    ('João', 'Matematica', 6),
    ('Maria', 'Matematica', 4),
    ('Maria', 'Matematica', 4),
    ('Maria', 'Matematica', 4)


SELECT
    NOME                    AS NOME_ALUNO,
    MATERIA                 AS MATERIA,
    SUM(NOTA)               AS SOMA_NOTA,
    COUNT(ID)               AS TOTAL_NOTA,
    (SUM(NOTA)/COUNT(ID))   AS MEDIA,
    CASE
        WHEN (SUM(NOTA)/COUNT(ID)) <7 THEN 'Reprovado'
        else 'Aprovado'
    END                     AS RESULTADO
FROM ALUNOS
GROUP BY
    NOME,
    MATERIA
```

Saída:

```
NOME_ALUNO  MATERIA     SOMA_NOTA   TOTAL_NOTA  MEDIA       RESULTADO
João        Matematica  22.00       3           7.333333    Aprovado
Leonardo    Matematica  25.00       3           8.333333    Aprovado
Maria       Matematica  12.00       3           4.000000    Reprovado
```

Comment: desculpa pelo vacilo:  essa seria a tabela que estou tentando criar uma função que calcula a media das coluna  BolNota1 ,BolNota2  e se for >= 7 o aluno deve ser considerado aprovado se nao reprovado
IF OBJECT_ID('TbBoletim') IS NULL
CREATE TABLE TbBoletim(
BolCod INTEGER NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
BolNota1 DECIMAL(5,1),
BolNota2 DECIMAL(5,1),
BolFalta INTEGER,
MatCod INTEGER,
dessecod INTEGER
);

Comment: @LuzineteMaciel adicione ela na pergunta, usando o botão [edit]

Comment: (*1*) Observação: as colunas BolNota1 e BolNota2 não podem fazer parte da cláusula GROUP BY; (*2*) Sugestão: como está somando colunas, verifique se o conteúdo existe (isto é, se não há NULL) antes de somar. Isto evita casos como  (NULL + 8) = NULL